# Change the file names.I want to make my code run faster

Tags: c, strtok

Defined function char * filename (char * file, int num)
Requirements: Enter a file name: test.txt 1
Output: test_1.txt
Input: test
Output: test_1

Here is my code

```
char *filename(char *file, int num)
{
    if(NULL == file || num <= 0)        
    {
        printf("parameter error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char *buf = file, *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    char temp[num];

    while (*buf != '.' && *buf != '\0') 
    {
        buf++;
        if(*buf == '\0')
        {
            strcat(file ,"_1");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    ptr1 = strtok(file, ". ");  
    ptr2 = strtok(NULL, ". ");  
    ptr3 = strtok(NULL, ". ");  

    strcpy(temp, ptr2); 

    strcat(file, "_");  
    strcat(file, ptr3); 
    strcat(file, ".");  
    strcat(file, temp); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return -1`? Surely you can think of something more appropriate to return here (or else, change the function prototype to return `int`). Also, please explain what exactly the problem is. Dumping your code here along with "**I want**" in the title is a very poor way for demonstrating your effort on the problem, or even in explaining what exactly the problem is (i.e., what makes you think that your code is not fast enough)!

Comment: return -1 is not good,I want to achieve parameter error then quit.

Comment: You found the string terminator, where you could have done `strcpy(buf,"_1");` but you call `strcat` which will look for the string terminator all over again.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `strtok()` to assure the operation was successful.    How do you know there is enough room in the buffer array pointed to by `file` to hold the new characters.

Comment: are you familiar with the function: `basename()`?

Comment: suggest the caller check the command line parameters, rather than waiting until the posted function is called.

Answer (score 1):

the following code compiles cleanly and performs the desired function

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGIT_LEN (15)

char *filename(char *file, int num)
{
    char * modifiedFileName = NULL;
    if( NULL == (modifiedFileName = malloc( strlen( file) +MAX_DIGIT_LEN ) ) )
    {
        perror( "malloc for room for expanded file name failed");
        //exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        return NULL;
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    char * base = NULL;
    if( NULL == (base =  strtok( file, ".") ) )
    {
        perror( "strtok failed to find . in file name");
        //exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        return NULL;
    }

    // implied else, strtok found .

    strcpy( modifiedFileName, base );
    char newChars[ MAX_DIGIT_LEN ] = {'\0'};  // 15 to allow for large numbers
    sprintf( newChars, "_%d.", num);

    strcat( modifiedFileName, newChars );

    char * ext = NULL;
    ext = base + strlen(base);

    strcat( modifiedFileName, ext );

    return( modifiedFileName );
} // end function: filename
```

Of course, the caller will need to pass the returned pointer to `free()` when done using it.